# How to increment VueJS Router Link ID by 1?

Tags: vue.js, router

I have

```
<router-link
        :to="{ name: 'painting', params: { id: parseInt(this.id) + 1 } }"
        >Next</router-link
      >
```

I thought I could go to the same path + 1.

The URL changes to + 1 (at first click only). But the page won't reload.

If I check on the second time, the `href` is still the same ID, it doesn't add 1. I imagine is because it won´t reload.

Here´s my router specs:

```
{ path: "/painting/:id?", name: "painting", component: Painting }
```

Now I´ve tried:

```
<router-link
        :to="{
          name: 'painting',
          params: { id: Number(this.$route.params.id) + 1 },
        }"
        >Next</router-link
      >
```

And the URL changes, but the  doesn´t.

Comment: What does your console say, what about the network tab?

Comment: What is `this.id` in your codes? Is it defined in `data` property?

Comment: @NimaEbrazeh, this.id is basically the ID from the URL: this.id = this.$route.params.id;

Comment: @NickvanderWaal I´ve changed it to <router-link
        :to="{
          name: 'painting',
          params: { id: Number(this.$route.params.id) + 1 },
        }"
        >Next</router-link
      > but still don´t work

Answer (score 0):

Used

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```